# .append() behaving strangely by outputing value twice

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
     var checkValue = jQuery(this).attr("value");
     if(jQuery(this).is(':checked'))
         jQuery("#myResults").append( checkValue );
});
```

I have the above code which is working fine except it's placing the value twice. For example if my check box value is:

> **RED**

After I click on the check box it outputs:

> **REDRED**

I can't see where it's going wrong. I am using jQuery v1.8.3

I found this thread with the same problem 
[jQuery append calling twice][1]
but it doesn't match my situation, any information is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Issue has been fixed, like David said, the problem was in another unrelated area of my code. Thanks to everyone for the help, Stackoverflow is an invaluable resource for programmers!

Comment: It's verbose, but it seems to work fine ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vGZwZ/)), except in the case of subsequent clicks (as the `#myResults` element isn't cleared before the next string is appended); and do remember that you can use the DOM ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vGZwZ/1/)), which is a little more efficient than invoking jQuery for every little thing.

Comment: Also you can just empty the html when you click on the checkbox. Also try caching your selectors if they are being used multiple times .. http://jsfiddle.net/vGZwZ/3/

Comment: David I see your example working exactly as it should, but for whatever reason it's still firing twice on my end. I am a lot stronger with server side language, but this needs to be performed on the front end before form submit. Can you show me an example of how I would use the DOM to perform this action. Thanks so much for the help

Ultimately what I want to end up with is a set of check boxes that append to a variable when checked. Then when unchecked remove their value. For example RED-checked HD-checked CAR-checked myvar="REDHDCAR" then, RED-checked HD-unchecked CAR-checked myvar="REDCAR"

Comment: I knwow this is going away from the scope of my original question, but since you mention the DOM might be a cleaner solution I figure it would help to have all the information.

Answer (score 1):

***edited***

I think this code will work for you.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    if(this.checked)
        $("#myResults").html(this.value);
});
```

Comment: `this.value`, you don't need jQuery to retrieve the value. And if you do, then you should (in 1.6+) use `prop()` not `attr()`. And, other than avoiding creating a variable, what does that change from the posted code the OP showed (which already worked in isolation, which suggests the problem is elsewhere in his/her code).

Answer (score 0):

try to setting html instead of appending it:

```
jQuery("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
var checkValue = jQuery(this).attr("value");
 if(jQuery(this).is(':checked'))
jQuery("#myResults").html(checkValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I would use html, but for this specific case the values need to be appended to the end. I'm appending to a div for testing purposes but this will be part of a greater whole